# Running a SolidWorks macro from Python

Tags: python, vba, solidworks

I write a txt file on Python which contains the coordinates of the control points, which is then read by SolidWorks.

I have written a macro on SolidWorks to save the new modified STL file.

```
import numpy as np 
import os
def GenerateCoordinates(low,high,size):
    X=np.random.randint(low,high,size)
    Y=np.random.randint(low,high,size)
    #Z=np.random.randint(low,high,size)
    return X,Y
X=GenerateCoordinates(0,6,7)[0]
Y=GenerateCoordinates(0,4,7)[1]
k=0
sketch_number=1 #Generate coordinates
g=open('Cdd.txt','w')
for i in range(1,len(X)):
    g.write('CoordinatesX'+str(i)+'='+str(X[i])+'\n')
    g.write('"D'+str(k)+'@Sketch'+str(sketch_number)+'"'+'=CoordinatesX'+str(i)+'\n')
    k+=1
    g.write('CoordinatesY'+str(i)+'='+str(Y[i])+'\n')
    g.write('"D'+str(k)+'@Sketch'+str(sketch_number)+'"'+'=CoordinatesY'+str(i)+'\n')
    k+=1
    #g.write('CoordinatesZ'+str(k)+'='+str(Z[i])+'\n')
    #g.write('D'+str(k)+'@Sketch'+str(sketch_number)+'=CoordinatesZ'+str(k)+'\n')
g.close() #writes coordinates in a txt file then saves the txt file

os.popen('"C:/Users/Public/Desktop/Program Files/SOLIDWORKS Corp/SOLIDWORKS/.exe"') #I want to call the macro that rebuilds the solidworks part with the modified coordinates.
```

How do I run the macro from Python, to import the new file into Python?

Comment: I tried this os.popen('"C:/Users\sm5126\Downloads\Python\Python\GetPath.swp /m path to the macro"'), the thing is it gives me this error is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. when I put the solidworks path

Comment: That doesnt tell us much, but it's supposed to be C:\ not C:/

Comment: I have modified it, and the command still does not run the macro! Though the solidworks path I put is C:/Users/Public/Desktop/Program Files/SOLIDWORKS Corp/SOLIDWORKS/.exe , the one I find when I check the software's properties. Yet python does not recognize it?

Comment: You have `SOLIDWORKS/.exe` do you mean `SOLIDWORKS.exe` ?? Or is that a folder and you forgot to name the exe file?

Comment: I have thought about removing the / (because I just copied-pasted the name of the path- Thought it does not work even when i remove the / before the exe. I have added my code in the question as well as what everything does! Thank you so much

Comment: `SOLIDWORKS/.exe` is definitely not right. I do not use solidworks or python, but i know that cannot be right. You will need to double check that... you cannot just put `.exe` at the end of a path.

Comment: Did you look into what the name of the exe file is yet? Others are not going to add any more comments or answers until you can get that first.

Comment: I would like to get the os.popen to open solidworks, so I thought taking the solidworks path and execute it with exe would open it. Otherwise, I am not sure I understand what you mean by the exe file? Thank you a whole lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update in case someone bumps into the same problem: the \m should not be included in the brackets. So for my example, it would be:
os.popen('"C:/Users/Public/Desktop/Program Files/SOLIDWORKS Corp/SOLIDWORKS/.exe" \m "Path to the macro"'). However, this just opens the macro without unfortunately running it.

Comment: Hi, please mark your answer as an accepted answer if you have solved your issue. This will make it more helpful for people who will stumble on a similar problem later on~